# How do I do an IF in Microsoft SQL SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am an absolute beginner in SQL.
Example:
I want to do a query to select people whose names begin with X **if the result is 0**, I want to select people whose names begin with Y.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: So, are you saying the results with peoples names starting with Y should not appear if results are found for values of X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is a better solution:

```
select * from table where name like 'X%'

if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
   select * from table where name like 'Y%'
```

Comment: Looks brilliant. I am going to give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I interpret the question as: show names starting with Y if no names starting with X are found.
This solution will be fast as it will short-cut the exists from the moment 1 record is found

```
if exists(select * from table where name like 'X%')
  begin
    select * from table where name like 'X%'
  end
else
  begin
    select * from table where name like 'Y%'
  end
```

Ideally the name column is indexed for this to work well.

Comment: This code will execute the 'select * from table where name like 'X%'' twice a time! This is ugly solution!

Comment: It will shortcut once the first record is hit in the exists statement. Performance wise it will be fine & only returns one resultset.

Comment: Filip, your interpretation is correct. But I don't see any IF or EXISTS keywords in MS SQL. I am doing straight SQL query. I don't code in C or Basic. Thanks.

Comment: IF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx ; EXISTS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much robyaw. It shows how little I know. I am going to read the pages you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do perform this in a single SQL statement, but they are extremely expensive (both in time and resources). You would be best served to do this kind of logic in a stored procedure.

Comment: "they are extremely expensive" -- I think you rather mean they are *relatively* expensive. If the table's cardinality is relatively low, for example, the the expense of a set-based solution will be absolutely negligible. Always test at least two candidate solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a set-based solution:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE NAME LIKE 'X%'
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE NAME LIKE 'Y%'
       AND NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT * 
                         FROM table AS T1
                        WHERE T1.NAME LIKE 'X%'
                      );
```